# login incorrect in cakephp even all is correct

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm New to CakePHP is an amazing PHP framework I'm trying to build a new application 
so I get to the part of login page this is my code when I try to login I get ' incorrect login ' 
and the password is hashed

AppController

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
        $this->Auth->allow('display');
}

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => ' email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'user',
                'action' => 'login'
            ]
        ]);

    /*
     * Enable the following component for recommended CakePHP security settings.
     * see https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html
     */
    //$this->loadComponent('Security');
}
}
```

//UserController

```
public function login(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if($user){
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'reference']);
        }
        // Bad Login
        $this->Flash->error('Incorrect Login');
    }
}

// Logout
public function logout(){
     $this->Flash->success('You are logged out');
     return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

//Login.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __("Merci de rentrer vos nom d'utilisateur et mot de passe") ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->control('username') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->control('password') ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Se Connecter')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What function are you using to hash the password? If it is `password_hash()` is the column in which you're storing the password in the database at least 60 characters wide?

Comment: There's a whitespace in your `fields` configuration's `username` value, also that config doesn't match your form control names.

Comment: @JayBlanchard this is what I use to hash my password :  protected function _setPassword($value)
    {
        if (strlen($value)) {
            $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();

            return $hasher->hash($value);
        }
    }

Comment: @ndm can you show me what's wrong on my config ?

Comment: @Soufian . ```'username' => ' email'```would be ```'username' => 'email'``` !  ```' email'```vs ```'email'```

Comment: @Salines I deleted the space before 'email' and still the same thing

Comment: @Soufian show us your users table, or password column

Comment: As mentioned your control names also don't match, if you really want to query the `email` field in the database, then you also need to name your control `email` instead of `username`, ie the control names should match the field config values.

Comment: @ndm I did what you told me and I get this 'Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Users.username' in 'where clause''